# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.Object)' method

Tags: silverlight

I am following Pete's tutorial on build my first silverlight application.
http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/build-your-first-silverlight-web-application/

However, since I am not using the database provided in the tutorial, I stuck at the final step which probably because of the data type conversion. Can anyone help me on that? Thanks!

The error_stub is uniqueidentifier in my case. And even if I remove ToString, it's still reporting error - cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid' to 'String'

I would appreciate if anyone can help me on this. Thanks!

```
public class ErrorService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public List<Error> GetError()
    {
        using (errorlogEntities context = new errorlogEntities())
        {
            return (from c in context.ERRORs
                    select new Error()
                    {
                        error_stub = c.error_stub


                    }).Take<Error>(200).ToList<Error>();

        }
    }

    // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]

}

public class Error
{
    public string error_stub { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: So, "c.error_stub" is a GUID? If so, that exception makes perfect sense. Can you post the .ToString() code you mention that you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution:

```
public class Error
{
    public Guid error_stub { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The vorrtex response is correct. You can also add a .ToString() to c.error_stub. I'll look something like this:

```
error_stub = c.error_stub.ToString()
```

Hope it helps